# NGINX reverse proxy setting not redirecting to specified target, still shows default centos index page

Tags: nginx, centos, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a simple reverse setting on my GCE:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
       proxy_pass http://192.168.49.2:31968/;
    }
}
```

I have tested and restarted the service:
sudo service nginx restart

But when I try and curl http://localhost, I still get the default Centos index page rather than expected content from http://192.168.49.2:31968/

I have checked my nginx.conf to see if there is any weird settings overriding but don't see anything strange:

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }
    }

# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#
#    server {
#        listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        server_name  _;
#        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
#
#        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
#        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
#        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
#        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
#        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
#
#        location / {
#        }
#
#        error_page 404 /404.html;
#        location = /404.html {
#        }
#
#        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#        location = /50x.html {
#        }
#    }

}
```

Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

When you say you get the 'Centos index page', you mean the default 'Welcome to Nginx' page?

So I guess you want to override the default page?

Don't change the nginx.conf.
Go to /etc/nginx/sites-available, and there you find a default file.
change the content of the file to:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
       proxy_pass http://192.168.49.2:31968/;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I meant that page. 
In the Centos installation, I don't see any sites-available folder.
Are you sure it really requires sites-available for such a simple reverse proxy setup?